# Center a div in WP using CSS, or a hook

Tags: html, wordpress, hook

Hi I just customized my WP theme to have a Rev Slider as the header on the Home Page only.
http://test.texaswagyuassociation.com/

Now the last step is to center the #site-header-inner div (containing the logo & search box) to be in the 1069px content area, not over to the left.

My goal is simply to center that div, then have the logo size down and be in the upper left of the rev slider instead of the lower left, just be in the correct upper left position when on mobile.

It seems like this can be done with CSS, but nothing is working. The theme support says I need to "use theme hooks to add an extra wrapper around the #site-header-inner div (may be easier) so it keeps it's width."

Can this be done with CSS only or do I need to use a hook? I know nothing about hooks. If anyone can give me the exact steps to achieve this I would GREATLY appreciate it.

I have added this custom CSS to remove the header and finally get it the way it is, so close.

```
body.home #site-header {
background: none;
}

body.home #site-header-inner {
position: absolute;
top: 51px /*offset topbar*/
}

body.home #site-logo,
body.home #header-aside {
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

something like?:

```
   body.home #site-header-inner {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      max-height: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are theme based functionality except wp_footer and wp_head, so you need to ask your theme author what are the available hooks on your theme and if they even support the kind of hooks you wanted.

Best way is to structure your #site-header-inner inner HTML div like this

```
<div id="site-header-inner" class="container clr">
    <div> <!-- Add another div wrapper -->
        <div id="site-logo" class="site-branding clr header-two-logo">
            ........
        </div>
        <aside id="header-aside" class="clr visible-desktop header-two-aside">
            ........        
        </aside><!-- #header-two-aside -->
    </div><!-- another div wrapper close tag-->
</div>
```

Then you could simple apply css like this,

```
/** Always set an outer wrapper with position relative for absolute div**/
#outer-wrap #site-header-inner {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
/** Absolute Div will inherit the maximum width of its outer wrapper**/
#site-header-inner > div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20px;
}
```

If its harder to edit HTML tags, you can just insert div wrapper using jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('#site-header-inner').wrapInner("<div></div>");
});
```